# Retrieve Orbeon form that was saved as a draft

Tags: orbeon

I've published an Orbeon form. I've enabled two form button, Save and Send:

- The action of the Send button is overridden using `properties-local.xml` file. It sends the data to my web application.
- The issue is with the Save button. I'm aware that the Save button saves the form in the Orbeon database as a draft. What should I do to retrieve that form with the saved data and display it again?

I'm aware that while sending the form to my web application endpoint, the following values are returned: document, process, valid, app, form, form-version and language.

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve that form"? Do you want to access it from your code through an API? Do you want to show it again to users at a latter point from your own app?

Comment: @avernet, I want to show it again to users at a latter point of time. And yes, the form is embedded in a JSP page.

Comment: Do you want to be able to read back the data saved to the database and edit it? Then you need to pass the `edit` mode and the `documentId` to the [Java embedding API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/link-embed/java-api.html#basic-configuration).

Comment: @ebruchez, doing so, will the saved draft reopen?

Comment: @mark42inbound By "saved draft" are you referring to the document saved by the `save-draft` process? If so, then yes, it will open the document previously saved.

Comment: Which process is called while saving the form? Is it save-final or save-draft? Note: I haven't overridden the save process.

Comment: @ebruchez, I was able to edit the form by providing the action as edit and the document ID. Can you add it as an answer to this question?

Comment: @mark42inbound Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling the Java embedding API, simply provide the following:

```
<%
    API.embedFormJava(
        request,
        out,
        myAppName,    // set this as needed
        myFormName,   // set this as needed
        "edit",       // the `edit` mode loads form data from the database
        myDocumentId, // this is the id of the document in the database
        null,
        null
    );
%>
```

With this, the form will load the data from the database and the user will be able to make changes to the data.